# How does `flex-grow:0` get interpreted?

Tags: css, flexbox

I wonder if `flex-grow:0` in the Flexbox model means

- `width:0`
  or
- "grow=0"
  .

If it means the latter, is it save to say that this is equal to `width:auto` and `display:inline-block`, i.e. it takes just as much width as needed to display?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`flex-grow:0` simply means that the item won't be resized during item size calculation to accommodate flex container's full **main axis size**.

[Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-grow-factor) describes it as:

> This `<number>` component sets `flex-grow` longhand and specifies the flex grow factor, which determines how much the flex item will grow relative to the rest of the flex items in the flex container when positive free space is distributed. When omitted, it is set to `1`.

I've emphasized *main axis size* above beacuse you should know that `flex-grow` is related to main axis of the flex container which can be width or height dimension depending on `flex-direction` and writing directionality of user browser.

Therefore we can't assume being equal to your assumption.

But when we're talking about `flex-direction: row` and writing directionality LRTB (left to right, top to bottom) then they do work in the similar fashion as `width: auto;`. Items do appear as inlined, but they still don't render the same because no whitespace is being added for each line break in HTML source as we normally see with usual inline elements.

#### How about `width: 0`?

Flex item width is associated with `flex-basis` property rather than grow factor. Although flex properties have precedence over `width` or `height` of items when grow and shrink factors are defined and non-zero.

Comment: I'm not sure why it says "when omitted, it is set to 1", the default value of "flex-grow" is 0. Flex items won't take more space than they need if you don't specify "flex-grow"

Answer (score 3):

**A few examples of `flex-grow: 0`**

The following examples might be helpful for those learning flex-box.

Basically, flex-grow does the following:

- check if the container is wider than all children
- if yes, distribute the left-over space proportionally to the `flex-grow` of each child

So, if we have two children with e.g. `flex-grow` equal respectively to:

- 1 and 1: give both the same share of the extra space
- 1 and 2: give the second 2x more than the first
- 0 and 1: give the second infinitely more than the first (1/0 = infinity), i.e. don't grow the first at all and grow the second to fill the rest of container
- 0 and 0: none of them will grow, and the children can end up being smaller than the container. So 0 can be seen to be as a slightly magic value and simply meaning "never grow this" than a proportion in the more strict sense (since the meaning of 0/0 is not well defined).

Here's how the code below render on Chromium 85:

[image]

```js
for (let container of document.getElementsByClassName('container')) {
  const widths = [];
  for (let child of container.children) {
    widths.push(child.offsetWidth)
  }
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', `<div>widths: ${widths.join(' ')}</div><br>`)
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}
.container .child-1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 2em;
}
.container .child-2 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 2em;
}
.container .subchild-1 {
  background-color: green;
}
.container .subchild-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
ruler
<div class="container"><div style="width: 50px; background-color: magenta;">50</div><div style="width: 50px; background-color: cyan;">50</div><div style="width: 50px; background-color: magenta;">50</div><div style="width: 50px; background-color: cyan;">50</div><div style="width: 50px; background-color: magenta;">50</div><div style="width: 50px; background-color: cyan;">50</div><div style="width: 50px; background-color: magenta;">50</div><div style="width: 50px; background-color: cyan;">50</div></div>

flex-grow 1 1. Adds 75 (175 = 100 + 75) to child-1 and 75 to child-2 (225 = 150 + 75)
<div class="container">
  <div class="child-1" style="flex-grow: 1;"><div class="subchild-1" style="width: 100px">100</div></div>
  <div class="child-2" style="flex-grow: 1;"><div class="subchild-2" style="width: 150px">150</div></div>
</div>

flex-grow 1 2. child-1 wants 100, child-2 wants 200. We have 100 left to 400. child-2 to grow 2x more than child-1 (33 vs 67).
<div class="container">
  <div class="child-1" style="flex-grow: 1;"><div class="subchild-1" style="width: 100px">100</div></div>
  <div class="child-2" style="flex-grow: 2;"><div class="subchild-2" style="width: 200px">200</div></div>
</div>

flex-grow 0 1. child-1 simply cannot grow, so child-2 takes up all remaining space.
<div class="container">
  <div class="child-1" style="flex-grow: 0"><div class="subchild-1" style="width: 50px">50</div></div>
  <div class="child-2" style="flex-grow: 1"><div class="subchild-2" style="width: 50px">50</div></div>
</div>

flex-grow 0 0. How much is 300 divided by 0? Doesn't matter, if neither can grow we go below the min.
<div class="container">
  <div class="child-1" style="flex-grow: 0"><div class="subchild-1" style="width: 50px">50</div></div>
  <div class="child-2" style="flex-grow: 0"><div class="subchild-2" style="width: 50px">50</div></div>
</div>

flex-grow 0 0. No more space left, all fits perfectly. flex-grow 0 does nothing.
<div class="container">
  <div class="child-1" style="flex-grow: 0"><div class="subchild-1" style="width: 100px">100</div></div>
  <div class="child-2" style="flex-grow: 0"><div class="subchild-2" style="width: 300px">300</div></div>
</div>

flex-grow 0 0. Minimal content size doesn't fit, nothing we can do about it.
<div class="container">
  <div class="child-1" style="flex-grow: 0"><div class="subchild-1" style="width: 100px">100</div></div>
  <div class="child-2" style="flex-grow: 0"><div class="subchild-2" style="width: 400px">400</div></div>
</div>
```